# Parsing error: Error while parsing config - JSON5: invalid character ?? at 1:1

Tags: reactjs, parsing, npm, build, json5

npm run build

covet-project@0.1.0 build
react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

[eslint]
src\About.js
Line 0: Parsing error: Error while parsing config - JSON5: invalid character '�' at 1:1

src\App.js
Line 0: Parsing error: Error while parsing config - JSON5: invalid character '�' at 1:1

src\Body.js
Line 0: Parsing error: Error while parsing config - JSON5: invalid character '�' at 1:1... for every file...

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";

const AppLayout = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(true);

  const setIsLoggedIn = (value) => {
    setLoggedIn(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {!loggedIn ? (
        <Login setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} />
      ) : (
        <div className="app">
          <Header setLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} />
          <Outlet />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

Comment: Please include the code as well  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example